# iOS: NSObject call and detecting which UIVIewController made the call

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, nsobject

Hopefully this is an easy one...

I have an NSObject with methods that is used in multiple UIViewControllers (the NSObject is imported in my .pch file).

The UIViewControllers then make calls to the NSObject like so;

`[ThisNSObject doSomething];`

This is all working to plan so there's no issue there... however, I would love the method *doSomething* to be able to detect WHICH UIViewController made the call to that NSObject. Then, based on that information I can manipulate the UIViewController in any given way.

The reason I need this is because if I have a UITabBar with each Tab loading a different UIViewController, but all making a call to the global NSObject, I need to direct further action to that one specific UIViewController.

I know I have access to *keyWindow*, but I'm not sure this is exactly what I'm after.

Any suggestions would be great, thank you.

Roy

**EDIT:** 
Actually, perhaps in the NSObject I can detect which tab is currently selected, then get the top View in the stack... and make a reference like that? Does anyone have thoughts on why this would be a bad idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using runtime code you could probably drill back through the call stack, but it's a rather complex solution to a simple problem. I would suggest that you look to the APIs for inspiration and modify your doSomething method to take a controller argument like this:

```
-(void) doSomethingWithViewController:(UIViewController *) viewController;
```

This way when you can the doSomething method you pass a reference to self like this:

```
[theObject doSomethingWithViewController:self];
```

And your problem is solved - simply.

P.S. if you have other parameters, an alternative signature style might be

```
-(void) viewController:(UIViewController *) viewController doSomethingWithX:(id) x;
```

It all depends on what makes the best sense to you.

Answer (score 1):

I sort of agree with @drekka's answer, but it has an issue...the code line:

```
- (void) viewController:(UIVIewController*)viewController doSomething;
```

is not syntactically correct.  However, he sort of redeems himself by putting another solution that is correct:

```
- (void) doSomethingWithViewController:(UIViewController*) viewController;
```

An alternative, since it doesn't seem that passing the ViewController as an argument really makes sense in your situation, is to use delegation on your custom class and have the viewController subscribe as a delegate.  For example:

```
@protocol MyCustomNSObjectDelegate;

@interface MyCustomNSObject : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<MyCustomNSObjectDelegate delegate;

- (void) doSomething;

@end

@protocol MyCustomNSObjectDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void) myCustomNSObject:(MyCustomNSObject*)myObject takeFurtherActionWithData:(NSString*)someData;
@end
```

Then in your UIViewController

```
#import "MyCustomNSObject.h"

@interface MyUIViewController : UIViewController <MyCustomNSObjectDelegate>

...
```

Then set the MyCustomNSObject's delegate property to the UIViewController before you call doSomething.  In the doSomething method, after if finishes doing "something", at the end of the method add:

```
[self.delegate myCustomNSObject:self takeFurtherActionWithData:@"change this to whatever type you need here"];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oops, teach me for typing code rather than cutting and pasting :-) Will correct my answer.